# Where can I find all the logic of an Asp.net core MVC with built in Authentication?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

When creating an MVC project and checking "Individual User Accounts" authentication, there is login & register added with all the logic & everything needed to make it work but I can't find the code, could anyone please refer me to the right direction

Comment: you tagged `mvc-3` and `asp.net-core`, which it it?

Comment: I created a ASP.NET Core Web Application & then selected an MVC Web app.
typeof (Controller).Assembly.GetName().Version says that its version 3.0.0 so...not sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `asp.net-core` Identity, all the logic, controllers and views are built in by default. **However**, you can "scaffold" Identity. This will create everything and allow you to customize or extend it.

More on [scaffolding here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio), complete with easy instructions.